# FIrebase 3 query to return value that matches child key/value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just upgraded my iOS application to use firebase 3 and a query which was working in firebase 2 no longer works in firebase 3.

The old query was written as follow.

```
fireBaseUser.queryOrderedByChild("displayName").queryEqualToValue(friendDisplayName)
      .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
}
```

where friendDisplayName could have been 'someguy1' and that would have returned the object that someguy1 was part of.

Now however, the same query returns nothing on firebase 3. I get the feeling that it is because firebase 3 isn't looking inside the child objects themselves, it's looking for displayName to be the actual child itself. If i update it to this query for example it returns as expected.

```
    database.child("0hfTq3CTtFWNFvG0dmea1rAYpoW2").queryEqualToValue("someguy1", childKey: "displayName").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
}
```

but obviously this won't work as a solution for me because I don't want to have to parse through the child nodes and then search through them etc.. the way i see it one solution would be if firebase had a 'catch all' where you could specify a child to be something like

```
database.child(*****).etc
```

where the **** can be any value, doesn't need to be specified in the actual query.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I've attached the firebase JSON layout below.

Thanks!

```
 {
      "users" : {
        "0hfTq3CTtFWNFvG0dmea1rAYpoW2" : {
          "displayName" : "someguy1",
          "pushOptions" : 1,
          "pushToggle" : false
        },
        "9BATNLBnnoXMOvK4lHtQfmNGJJy1" : {
          "displayName" : "someguy2",
          "pushOptions" : 0,
          "pushToggle" : true
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found out that despite there being no documentation on it, displayName acts as a keyword - the user object provided to you by firebase now offers a displayName property, but unlike most other databases, you can't use displayName in any other nodes or children - well you can, but it's not searchable. In the end changing the displayName property to be userName solved all my problems.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue but I don't quite follow you with the userName field ?

Comment: So a firebase user object has a displayName property now - it didn't used to , it would just use the email address for the username. Because of this, it's not become a reserved keyword when you do a search. This is from memory, and I don't entirely remember how I solved it, but basically, because displayName is a reserved name, changing it to userName fixed up everything. Let me know if you need me to dig out some code.